# Typhoon: injecting a view controller provider

Tags: objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

When using a hand made container/injector responsible for creating and managing the lifecycle of the objects in my graph I use the following pattern(I read in an article about DIY DI in ObjC):

Let's say we have a root view controller that wants to present another one(let's call it detail view controller) passing some data to it. What I normally do is to inject a provider block that takes the data as an argument and returns a new view controller to present. Here is some code...

```
@implementation RootViewController
{
    UIViewController (^detailViewControllerProvider)(SomeData *someData);
}

- (id) initWithDetailViewControllerProvider:(UIViewController (^)(SomeData *someData))detailViewControllerProvider
{
   //...
   _detailViewControllerProvider = detailViewControllerProvider;
   //...
}

// ...

- (void) presentDetailViewControllerWithData:(SomeData *)someData
{
    UIViewController *detailViewController = _detailViewControllerProvider(someData);
    [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

I could use a factory class as well but this way I avoid creating a new class just creating the provider block in my container class.

The problem comes when I want to use Typhoon as a DI container. How can I use the same pattern? In my detail view controller I am injecting other things and I want to keep using constructor injection, and prefer if it is created by the component factory, not by me. I could create a factory class to create the detail VC, injecting in it(the factory) the dependencies I want to inject later in my detail VC, but it seems too much work comparing to the block based solution.

I don't want to access my component factory from the root view controller and neither use setter injection for someData.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a factory.
It seems like a little overhead, but if you do TDD, it will drastically simplify your life as your can easily mock a factory and test your controller in isolation.
It will also work well with a typhoon.

Comment: Nice advice - this is the idea. . You can also use Typhoon as the factory itself. . (Although noted the OP doesn't necessarily want to to this). Added info below.

Comment: Mocking the provider block in a test fixture is as easy as mocking a factory, and I don't need to create one as I stated in my question.

Answer (score 2):

**To inject the TyphoonComponentFactory:**

- You can override the lifecycle method `- (void)typhoonSetFactory:(id)theFactory` in your class.
- In you assembly interface you can inject a property or argument with `self`

In any either case, any of your `TyphoonAssembly` interfaces can pose in front of the factory. So for example if you have an assembly called `NetworkAssembly`, you can define a property of type `NetworkAssembly` and inject the factory as that. The documentation for this feature is [here](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself).

You can use this approach to roll your own factory that:

- Pulls the static dependencies from the container.
- Instantiates the requirement component by injecting the static dependencies along with run-time arguments form your factory interface.

**Typhoon Factories w/ Runtime Arguments:**

Your `TyphoonAssembly` interfaces can now implement the above pattern:

Example:

```
- (UserDetailsController *)userDetailsControllerForUser:(User *)user
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[UserDetailsViewController class]   
        configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithPhotoService:user) 
            parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {

            [initializer injectParameterWith:[self photoService];
           [initializer injectParameterWith:user];
        }];
    }];
}
```

And now resolve the component:

```
User* aUser = self.selectedUser;
UserDetailsViewController* detailsController = 
    [assembly userDetailsControllerForUser:aUser];
```

The documentation for this feature is [here](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Types%20of%20Injections#injection-with-run-time-arguments).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I see some problems between the alternatives you offer. Using the assembly interface or the component factory are basically relying on singletons(the default instances) which is something I am trying to avoid. TyphoonComponentFactoryAware is a better solution but it implies setter injection and I want all my dependencies injected in the initializer if possible. I had a look to the sample app, which is using a container view controller but I don't need that, just want a classic navigation based app.

Comment: And TyphoonFactoryProvider seems a great solution but I cannot make it work... Will keep trying or otherwise I will implement a plain old factory like I said in my question.

Comment: What I have done is to create a plain old factory implementing TyphoonComponentFactoryAware on it, avoiding to inject anything in the factory(I get what I want from the component factory), and from it I create my detail view controller(s).

Comment: Both links are dead :S

Answer (score 1):

Your assembly interfaces can serve as factories - providing static dependencies along with run-time arguments. The documentation for this feature is [here](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Types-of-Injections#injection-with-run-time-arguments).

**Example:**

```
- (UserDetailsController *)userDetailsControllerForUser:(User *)user
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[UserDetailsViewController class]   
        configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithPhotoService:user) 
            parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {

            [initializer injectParameterWith:[self photoService];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:user];
        }];
    }];
}
```

**And now resolve the component:**

```
User* aUser = self.selectedUser;
UserDetailsViewController* detailsController = 
    [assembly userDetailsControllerForUser:aUser];
```

Comment: Hi Aleksey, I don't really see a solution for my original question apart of using injectParameterAtIndex:withObject: and passing a block that will access to the defaultFactory(something I don't like) to get the required dependencies and create the object... I will write a more detailed answer to this question illustrating the possible solutions I see for it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to inject assembly subclass as provider.
If you want to create detailsViewController depends on your runtime data - create DetailsViewControllerFactory which will do it for you.
I think if detailsViewController creation has business logic, then this work not for typhoon - but for your factory.